# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

When I was trying to connect my `phpmyadmin` on my `XAMPP`, it gave an error:

```
#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Can any help me to resolve it?

Comment: You can open your xampp with administrative right means Run as  administrator and then start Apache after that run MySQL it  works if you haven't any other issue..

Answer (score 22):

Okay, so i tried all of the answers and none of them worked.
If you are using different port than 3306 for MySQL you need to specify it in config.inc.php.

So since i was using port 3308, my solution was adding the following line in config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 3308;
```

add it right bellow the user, password or extension lines.

Comment: Thanks alot man. You literally saved my time after wasting so much time.

Comment: Yes this is the answer . I ve been trying for days. Thanks mate! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 11):

Go to

C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Temp

Delete all the files.It will work.

Comment: Worked for me. Have multiple installations of mysql, which must have caused the issue.

Answer (score 8):

Go to :

```
xampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

open the file config.inc.php
Go to line no:31

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
```

Change the line to :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
```

Restart your system.

[Reference](http://opensourcecmsinfo.com/2002-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it/)

Comment: Thanks pradip which u have posted u r answer very helped me.

Answer (score 7):

If your operating system is Windows 7:

- go to control panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services
- find mysql then right-click, click start

If your operating system is Linux (Ubuntu):

- in terminal type this command: sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

Good Luck

Comment: I get this error when I start mysql from services app.
Windows could not start the mysql service on Local Computer.
Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

Answer (score 5):

Please go to `c:\xampp\tmp` folder and delete all the files.
It works for me may help you.

Answer (score 3):

Please try changing `connect_type` in your `config.inc.php` from 'tcp' to 'http'. This file exists in the phpMyAdmin top level directory.

Existing line looks like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

New line should be looking like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'http';
```

Comment: Thanks u r answer has been used for me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're trying to connect to http://localhost/phpmyadmin.

From XAMPP control panel start both the Apache module and the MySQL module.

Comment: This worked for me, must be another issue for the OP

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `localhost`, type this in your address bar `localhost:<PORT>` (e.g. `localhost:88`)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if you delete your temporary files in windows in

> C:\Windows\Temp

and

> C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Temp

it works.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. I have two installs of xampp (one with php 5.6 and the other 7.1) and the error was shown to me after changing from one phpmyadmin (xampp php 7.1) to the other (xampp php5). After clearing the %SystemRoot%\Temp folder, all were good again.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your MySql service is running or not.

You can check it by searching **Services** in **Start** and then check the **status** of **mysql80** service. If your service is not running then start service by right clicking on it and then Start.

Or you can use CMD.

Open Command Prompt as administrator and then run `net start mysql80`.

Answer (score 0):

Just insures that the port no. in file - phpmyadmin (config.inc.php) and my.ini are same (mostly 3306) and not use by any other process[image][image]