# Error connecting to MYSQL on localhost: phpMyAdmin - Error

Tags: mysql

I am unable to connect to MYSQL. I am using XAMPP.  Every time I try I get this error:

```
phpMyAdmin - Error

#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

This is the MYSQL error log:

```
140827 17:12:18  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 182581223424
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 182581375516
InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 9836256 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 118A100
140827 17:13:22  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
140827 17:13:23  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 1189F04, 9836256 rows to undo

InnoDB: Progress in percents: 1140827 17:13:23  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140827 17:13:24 InnoDB: 5.5.36 started; log sequence number 182581375516
140827 17:13:24 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
140827 17:13:24 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
140827 17:13:24 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
```

Comment: are you using `wordpress`?

Comment: mysql's running. it's your phpmyadmin that's misconfigured on how it should connect to that server. either you've got the wrong IP in there, the IP is firewalled, or you're pointing at the wrong socket, exactly as the error message said.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712581/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it