# cannot access localhost/phpmyadmin in xampp error: err_connection_refused on google chrome.

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

Everything was working fine but suddenly when I tried to access my localhost/phpmyadmin I faced and error This webpage is not available. Error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I changed the listen and serverlocalhost to 8080 in httpd.confg and in the httpd-ssl.confg changed to VirtualHost *default*:4433 and ServerName localhost:4433. Is it because of that because it was not working before also so that is why I had to change it.

Comment: Did you try to reload mysql and phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yes tried it but its not working.

Comment: I would keep the defaults 443 / 80 ports on localhost, I am not sure if ssl will work on 4433 at all, are you sure that apache ssl port is ON ? You can search how to run SSL with xampp > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430574/how-do-i-use-https-ssl-in-xampp-while-using-virtual-hosts its not duplication but its the same question as yours

Comment: @AdityaBanerjee hmm, look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712581/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it

Answer (score -3):

try this "localhost:/phpmyadmin" eg. localhost:8080/phpmyadmin or localhost:4433/phpmyadmin

Comment: This answer need some more explanation.