# Unable to start MySQL on XAMPP Control Panel

Tags: mysql, xampp

I just installed XAMPP v3.2.2 by following [Derek Banas's youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdvVKywGlc0). I managed to run apache, but when I try to run MySQL, I get this message

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
11:31:35 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
11:31:35 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
```

I have been looking at other solutions on StackOverflow but none of them have worked for me.

Here is my [mysql_error.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-5RHn0Vl34GxYbR_rAkekTe2r7VmIGOci5606K7fJ6I) file.

This is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEjyX.jpg) I get when using phpMyAdmin.

I apologize for uploading the code. Not sure which parts were necessary!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712581/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it. could you please check this

Comment: have you installed skype ? if you have installed then change the port of skype